# Adding trendline as additional legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a scatter plot showing continuous data over time. My data are distinguished by two variables (type and level) which are represented in the legend. I have added a trendline to the data and would like to include it as a separate legend (apart from type and level) and label it "trendline". I would appreciate any advice on the most efficient way to accomplish this. Thank you!

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

perc <- c(.5, .49, .67, .5, .67, .73, .82)
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006)
type <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
type <- as.factor(type)
level <- c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4)
level <- as.factor(level)
data <- data.frame(year, perc, type, level)

ggplot(data, aes(x=year, y=perc, color = type, shape = level)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 17))
```

[image]

Comment: try adding `linetype=""` to the top level of the `ggplot` call

Comment: Thanks @user20650. That was what I was going for. I added `linetype = "Trendline"` to include a label (see response below)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
library(tidyverse)

perc <- c(.5, .49, .67, .5, .67, .73, .82)
year <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006)
type <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)
type <- as.factor(type)
level <- c(3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4)
level <- as.factor(level)
data <- data.frame(year, perc, type, level)

ggplot(data, aes(x=year, y=perc, color = type, shape = level, linetype = "Trendline")) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 17)) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Would something like this help?

Please note the new arguments I added under `geom_smooth`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=year, y=perc, group = type,
                 color = type, shape = level)) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = 'lm', 
              aes(group = 1, colour = "Trendline"),
              fullrange=TRUE, linetype=1) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "black", "blue")) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = c(16, 17, 18))
```

[image]

Comment: Random Question - Do we need to use group argument in aes() if we are already using the color argument?

Comment: @Pranjal It depends, but I don't think there's anything wrong with including it explicitly even when it's not necessary in a specific context. You can check the first two paragraphs of `?aes_group_order` for a discussion on this.

Comment: Thanks @DJV. That wasn't quite what I was going for because I wanted the trendline to be in a separate legend from type (see below what worked for me)

Comment: You're welcome and sorry I wasn't able to help you 100%.